# Only allowing one keypress

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I make sure the user only gets one key press and disable them from holding the key so value will not grow? The user can press the key down again, but cant not hold it down.thx

Comment: You're looking to check if a button is triggered, not pressed.

Comment: Can you show us what code you currently have?

Comment: How do you currently process input?

Answer (score 1):

The [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) message stores the previous key state in bit 30 of the `lParam` argument. If you only want to handle the initial keystroke, you can ignore all `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, where this bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

Handle [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) rather than `WM_CHAR`.

Bit 30 of lParam indicates the previous key state.

Comment: if  the keystroke is held long enough, multiple `WM_KEYDOWN` are sent. so this not solution

Comment: The [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) message comes with all information you need to determine, whether this is the first message sent in response to keyboard input, or part of the autorepeat feature. No need to handle `WM_KEYUP`.

Answer (score 0):

Any key that is pressed down one or more times, will be pressed up (released) only once... 
So provided that your callback function is

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

In order to filter multiple hits on the same key and capture them as one, you can use

```
if((nCode >= 0) && ((wParam == WM_KEYUP) || (wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP)))
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kb = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
```

where `kb->vkCode` will give you the pressed key and you will get this event message once.
As for disabling the user from hitting the same key many times (or long enough to generate 2 or more KEYDOWN events, it depends on the Keyboard settings of the Control Panel, so the best is just to capture multiple key hits as once.
[image: Keyboard Settings]